# How slow is * really?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Everybody states, that the `* { ... }` selector is very slow. But how slow is it really?

I always try to avoid it, but sometimes it's very useful. For example: `* + h1 { margin-top 1em; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it very simply: the universal selector `*` is only as slow as there are elements on your page.

Since [right-to-left matching browsers take each element and match it against all candidate rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left/5813672#5813672), every element will match `*` just fine. It by itself doesn't harm performance, but if you have many elements in your page or a very complex DOM, that's where it allegedly gets slow, but even then it doesn't visibly degrade browser performance.

Even something like `* + h1`, for example, is reasonable, since if you want to take matching performance into account, then a right-to-left matching browser will test that selector only on `h1` elements first, before checking if there's any element occurring before them (which really doesn't take much effort as `*` is basically a guaranteed match).

You may also wish to check out [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283579/is-a-selector-like-safe-to-use/9283660#9283660) to a similar question about `* + *` (that's *two* universal selectors!).

Comment: If you get complaints about `* + h1` because of the `*`, then `h1:not(:first-child)` is equivalent. You can then decide whether you want to sacrifice microseconds of performance or entire browser userbases (IE7 and 8 don't support `:not()`).

Comment: Very good answer and thanks for that clever `h1:not(:first-child)`.