# What is the logic behind sibling selectors * + * and * ~ *?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For this question I'm using the following markup:

```html
<body>
    <p>1</p> <!-- Paragraph 1 -->
    <p>2</p> <!-- Paragraph 2 -->
    <p>3</p> <!-- Paragraph 3 -->
</body>
```

From the [Selectors Level 3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors), the following selector rules apply:

```
*        any element
E + F    an F element immediately preceded by an E element
E ~ F    an F element preceded by an E element
```

Based on this, the following should occur:

```css
body + * { } /* Selects nothing as no elements precede body */
body ~ * { } /* As above. */
p + *    { } /* Selects Paragraph 2 and Paragraph 3 as these are preceded by p */
p ~ *    { } /* As above. */
* + *    { } /* As above. */
* ~ *    { } /* As above. */
```

**False!**

`* + *` and `* ~ *` are somehow able to select Paragraph 1 along with 2 and 3! Paragraph 1 isn't preceded by anything, so should be impossible to access:

```css
body + * { background: #000; }
body ~ * { background: #000; }
p ~ *    { color: #f00; }
p + *    { font-weight: bold; }
* + *    { text-decoration: underline; }
* ~ *    { font-style: italic; }
```

Result:

[image: Result example; paragraph 2 and 3 are red and all paragraphs are italic and underlined]

As you can see, paragraph 1 isn't preceded by the `body` or a phantom `p`, yet it is apparently preceded by something. It should have no custom styling applied to it at all, yet is somehow affected by those last two selectors. What is the logic behind this?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/WM4mu/).

Comment: your are missing `* ~ body`  and `* + body`

Comment: Same result - http://jsfiddle.net/WM4mu/1/

Comment: i just want to say  that `* ~ *` is _like_ `* ~ body` and `* + *` is _like_ if you write `* + body` that way these two rules apply to `body` and therefor body has the style `unterline` and `italic`

Comment: "no elements precede body" Or rather, "no elements *succeed* body"

Comment: Related: [Is a selector like \*+\* safe to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283579/is-a-selector-like-safe-to-use)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`* + *` Styles any element that is an immediate sibling of any element starting from the document root - Since the `<head>` is actually an immediate preceding sibling of the body (despite not being visible in your code) this selector targets the body and the last two paragraphs, since the first paragraph isn't immediately following another sibling element. All three paragraphs happened to be underlined due to the nature of `text-decoration` on block-level descendants in the normal flow.

`* ~ *` This is basically the same thing as above, except using the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) .. it styles downstream sibling element(s) that appear after the `<head>` regardless of whether they're immediate siblings or not. Since the `<body>` is the only sibling, this has the same effect as the above selector. The first paragraph is italicized due to inheritance.

`p ~ *` selects a sibling element that is *following* a `<p>` which in your example is the last two paragraphs. `p + *` styles any element that is immediate sibling of a paragraph, which would also be the last two `<p>` elements.

Comment: *"notice that I'm displaying the contents of the `<head>`"*, no you don't. The browser removes the `head` tag around the content. You cannot put `head` inside `body`. The explanation is still right though, so +1.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment: The color of `Test` is red because it is a child of `body`. The `<head>` tag from your HTML code is simply ignored.

Comment: Ah of course! I guess with testing this on JSFiddle I had completely ruled out the presence of the `head` tag!

Comment: "`* + *` = Styles *any* sibling element that *precedes* any element" - I think you mean "that *follows* any element".

Comment: Also, re: "that includes the body and *all* of its descendants": These selectors don't *select* all the body's descendants just because they follow head, since they only select *siblings* that follow their *siblings*. However, descendants of the body may inherit styling from the body, as @BoltClock pointed out.

Comment: @LarsH: Thank you once again - edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 20):

They are not applied to the first paragraph actually. To demonstrate this, let's change the stylesheet a bit:

```
* + *    { border-right: solid red }
* ~ *    { border-left: solid black; }
```

[image: demo]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fANpm/1/)

They are both applied to the "body" element which is in fact preceded by "head".

Answer (score 2):

That's an error in your test case. As you would expect, none of the selectors match the first paragraph, but **the styling from the `body` cascades to the paragraphs**!

Both `* + *` and `* ~ *` match `body` as it is preceded by a `head` tag. Thus, it receives `text-decoration:underline` and `font-style:italic`. That explains why all of the paragraphs are both underlined and italicised.

Comment: The paragraphs *inherit* the styles from `body`. Styles do not cascade from one element to another.