# CSS selector * + * definition?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What does the css selector * + * actually mean? You can see it it in google chrome's console when you do an inspect element. According to me it seems like applying a style to "Every second child" , but still want to be sure. Can anyone help me out?

Example:

```css
*+* {
   margin-top:1em;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the logic behind sibling selectors * + * and * ~ *?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695556/what-is-the-logic-behind-sibling-selectors-and)

Answer (score 11):

`* + *` means 'any element that has a previous sibling' - in other words, is not a first child.

Answer (score 5):

plus sign (+) means, if the second selectors directly is a sibling to the first selector:

```
h1+h2 {margin: 1em;}

h2 {margin: 2em;}
```

all `h2` have 2em `margin`, except the one that directly follows a `h1`, that one has 1em `margin`.

hopes that will make it clear for you

Answer (score 1):

As Specified in W3C documentation it represents the "Adjacent Sibling Combinator".

div + p

Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements

Answer (score 1):

Same as `*:not(:first-child)` but is shorter. I would prefer to write it out the long way as I think it's more readable, but I can see why a minifier would prefer `*+*`