# What does the CSS selector " .class > * + * {} " do?

Tags: html, css

What does the CSS selector `.class > * + * {}` do? I'm puzzled by `* + *` in particular.

Comment: That's the [Lobotomized Owl](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls/) selector.

Answer (score 1):

`* + *` means 'any element that has a previous sibling' - in other words, is not a first child.

You can refer to this question link:
[CSS selector *+* definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989318/css-selector-definition#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=*%20%2B%20*%20means%20%27any%20element,is%20not%20a%20first%20child.&text=all%20h2%20have%202em%20margin,that%20one%20has%201em%20margin%20.&text=As%20Specified%20in%20W3C%20documentation,the%20%22Adjacent%20Sibling%20Combinator%22.)

Comment: Even better SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695556/what-is-the-logic-behind-sibling-selectors-and).

Answer (score -1):

`.class` will select specific class

`.class > *` will select all elements with specified class

`.class > * + *` will select all first element of elements that will be children of `.class`

*For Example*

```
<div class="class">
  <span>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </span>
  <span>
    <h1></h1>
    <p></p>
  </span>
</div>
```

This will select all tags except first span and its elements

Comment: This is wrong. `.class > *` will select **every** direct child - in your example, the `span` tags. And `.class > * + *` will select every element **except** for the first. In your case, the first `span` will not be selected. In your example no `h1` tags would be selected. https://jsfiddle.net/sgurp9n1/

Comment: .class > * + *{
  background-color: green;
  color: green;
}

just use this and remove other css you use and you will understand . Except first every tag are selecting

Comment: _This will select all tags except first span and its elements_ This is still wrong. Your second rule `.class > *` is selecting and applying to the first `span` element. It's your third rule `.class > * + *` that is styling all `span` except the first. My first comment is partially irrelevant now, since you edited the original text.